# How to draw a gps marker on a rotated custom image map

Tags: math, gps

I need to draw a custom image map of a park in my App and add show gps markers on it.

However my problem is that the map should be drawn as a straight rectangle in my app (see below left), but in real life the park is rotated (see example below right)

I have the GPS coordinates of all the 4 corners of the real-live map together with the GPS coordinates of the markers but i'm stuck on how to calculate the (x,y) position for each marker for the map in my app where the map is displayed as a straight rectangle.

Any suggestions are welcome!

[image: Custom image map]

Code i have so far:

```
    public class GeoLocation
    {
        public double Lattitude { get; set; }

        public double Longitude { get; set; }

        public GeoLocation()
        {
        }

        public GeoLocation(double lat, double lon)
        {
            Lattitude = lat;
            Longitude = lon;
        }

        public double Angle(GeoLocation point)
        {
            var deltaX = point.Lattitude - Lattitude;
            var deltaY = point.Longitude - Longitude;
            return (Math.Atan2(deltaY, deltaX));
        }

        public GeoLocation Rotate(GeoLocation center, double angleInRad)
        {
            var s = Math.Sin(angleInRad);
            var c = Math.Cos(angleInRad);

            // translate point back to origin:
            var x = (double)(Lattitude - center.Lattitude);
            var y = (double)(Longitude - center.Longitude);

            // rotate point
            var xnew = x * c - y * s;
            var ynew = x * s + y * c;

            // translate point back:
            x = xnew + center.Lattitude;
            y = ynew + center.Longitude;
            return new GeoLocation(x, y);
        }
    }
        public partial class MainWindow : Window
        {
            public MainWindow()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
                var url = "file://c:\\db\\mapgrab.jpg";
                var bitmap = new BitmapImage();
                bitmap.BeginInit();
                bitmap.UriSource = new Uri(url, UriKind.Absolute);
                bitmap.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
                bitmap.EndInit();
                mapImg.Source = bitmap;


                var TopLeftGps = new GeoLocation(52.11070994543701, 4.411896866166349);
                var TopRightGps = new GeoLocation(52.11475153599096, 4.415646979517055);
                var BottomRightGps = new GeoLocation(52.1117075980591, 4.424232274309553);
                var currentPosGps = new GeoLocation(52.11129692591393, 4.4174530542349295);

                var imageWidth = 702;
                var imageHeight = 924;
                var angle = TopLeftGps.Angle(TopRightGps);
                var topRight = TopRightGps.Rotate(TopLeftGps, -angle);
                var bottomRight = BottomRightGps.Rotate(TopLeftGps, -angle);
                var maxX = topRight.Lattitude - TopLeftGps.Lattitude;
                var maxY = bottomRight.Longitude - topRight.Longitude;

                var markerPos = new GeoLocation(currentPosGps.Lattitude, currentPosGps.Longitude).Rotate(TopLeftGps, -angle);
                var diffX = markerPos.Lattitude - TopLeftGps.Lattitude;
                var diffY = markerPos.Longitude - TopLeftGps.Longitude;
                var percentageX = diffX / maxX;
                var percentageY = diffY / maxY;
                var posX = percentageX * imageWidth;
                var posY = percentageY * imageHeight;


                var markerImg = new Border();
                markerImg.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
                markerImg.Width = 32;
                markerImg.Height = 32;
                Canvas.SetLeft(markerImg, posX);
                Canvas.SetTop(markerImg, posY);
                canvas.Children.Add(markerImg);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

What you'r looking for is a 2D rotation transformation from the north aligned coordinates `(x,y)` to your rotated coordinates `(x',y')`

The rotation can be represented as a 2x2 matrix `R` and if we represent the coordinates as column vectors, then the computation will be:

`[x',y']=R*[x,y]`

Where `*` is [matrix multiplication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication), `R` is

[image]

And the angle theta is the desired rotation angle.

---

Marking the corner points thus:
[image]

theta can be computed be solving (for example in [wolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/)):

tan(theta) = (Ay-Dy) / (Ax-Dx)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. Here is a javascript example how to rotate points on a map. The coordinates are measured from the center point. The angle is in radiants.

```
var x_new_centered = -1 * y_centered * Math.sin(a) + x_centered * Math.cos(a)
var y_new_centered = y_centered * Math.cos(a) + x_centered * Math.sin(a);
```

And here you find a jsfiddle where a point is drawn on a not rotated, a rotated and rotated and cropped map: https://jsfiddle.net/vienom/4ger35uq/